# How can I know if a case has unread emails?

Tags: case, email2case, emailmessage

I've been thinking about using the "Status" field on EmailMessage for this. However I noticed that when the user accesses the email page the record has its status updated from 0 to 1 (unread to read), but the trigger on the Email Message object isn't run.

Is there a way to distinguish cases with unread emails from the ones with all messages read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best solution I've seen so far is a scheduled apex class that just goes through all cases and updates status rather than relying on a trigger.